# porque no acepta insert en una tabla si esta bien creada

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hola buenos dias o tardes, engo un programa que que es un punto de venta pero cuando quiero agregar el producto me marca el siguiente problema ya ejecute el comando desde sql manager y hay si acepta el insert

[image: Error de insert de visual studio a sql]

El scripts del insertar en la tabla de datos de detalles de clientes

```
 USE [dbventas]
    GO 
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[detalle_venta]
       ([idventa]
       ,[idproducto]
       ,[cantidad]
       ,[precio_unitario])
 VALUES
       (<idventa, int,>
       ,<idproducto, int,>
       ,<cantidad, decimal(18,2),>
       ,<precio_unitario, decimal(18,2),>)
      GO
```

Este esl procedimiento para almacenar datos en la tabla de detalles de venta

```
[dbo].[insertar_detalle_venta]
@idventa INT,
@idproducto INT,
@cantidad DECIMAL(18,2),
@precio_unitario DECIMAL(18,2)
AS
   BEGIN
INSERT INTO detalle_venta (idventa, idproducto, cantidad, precio_unitario)
VALUES (@idventa, @idproducto, @cantidad, @precio_unitario)
END
```

las llaves estan bien creadas no se que pueda ser
Esa es la  estructura de mi tabla de productos
[image: Estructura de productos]

esta es la estructura que tiene detalles

[image: estructura de detalles]

esa es la informacion que me muestra detalles de venta
[image: informacion de venta]

cuando lo ejecuto normal si me lo acepta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Existe el idProducto en tu tabla productos? El error te indica un problema de relacion con la tabla debo.producto. añade tu modelo de esas tablas

Comment: SELECT [idproducto]
      ,[idcategoria]
      ,[nombre]
      ,[descripcion]
      ,[stock]
      ,[precio_compra]
      ,[precio_venta]
      ,[fecha_vencimiento]
      ,[imagen]
  FROM [dbo].[producto]                                                                               
  esa es la informacion que hace llama la tabla de producto @Jakala

Comment: Hola @augustoS.Hernandez,  lo que te intentaron señalar es que el `idproducto` que estas enviando no debe existir en la DB producto o tenes un error al pasar dicho valor. Presiona [edit] y agrega el código que realiza esta acción.

Comment: cuando ejecuto el procedimiento de mostrar detalles de venta si me los muetsra el codigo es el siguiente       SELECT        dbo.detalle_venta.iddetalle_venta, dbo.detalle_venta.idventa, dbo.detalle_venta.idproducto, dbo.producto.nombre, dbo.detalle_venta.cantidad, dbo.detalle_venta.precio_unitario
FROM            dbo.detalle_venta INNER JOIN
                         dbo.producto ON dbo.detalle_venta.idproducto = dbo.producto.idproducto 
       order by iddetalle_venta desc

Comment: El mensaje de error dice claramente que no existe el ID producto en la tabla de productos, y por eso salta la integridad referencial. Si te funciona al ejecutarlo desde otro lado, es porque el dato de `idProducto` que estás enviando a la base de datos es distinto desde tu programa que desde una sesión interactiva, y el que envías desde tu programa, no existe.

Comment: @jachguate como puedo revisar eso

Comment: No muestras el código con el que insertas, diría que tan sencillo como imprimir el valor de las variables que usas para hacer el insert y verificar que el SQL sea correcto. si usas parámetros, que el orden/índice de los parámetros sea el correcto también.

Comment: muchas gracias ya quedo resulto el problema

Answer (score 0):

la forma en que corregi mi error es de la siguiente manera me falto ponerle el txtidproducto.text en la linea de codigo

```
Private Sub BTGuardar_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnguardar.Click
    If Me.ValidateChildren = True And Txtidventa.Text <> "" And Txtidproducto.Text <> "" And txtcantidad.Text <> "" And Txtprecio.Text <> "" Then
        Try
            Dim dts As New vdetalle_venta
            Dim func As New fdetalle_venta

            dts.gidventa = Txtidventa.Text
            dts.gidproducto = Txtidproducto.Text
            dts.gcantidad = txtcantidad.Text
            dts.gprecio_unitario = Txtprecio.Text

            If func.insertar(dts) Then
                If func.disminuir_stock(dts) Then

                End If
                MessageBox.Show("la venta es registardo correctamente", "Guardando registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                mostrar()
                limpiar()
                'cargar_detalle()

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("la venta no es registardo correctamete intnetale otra vez", "Guardando registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Faltan datos por registar intentelo otra vez", "Guardando registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
```